# Problema para ejecutar npm install request

Tags: javascript, asincronismo

estoy teniendo problemas para ejecutar el comando npm install request. Se supone que debería generarme dos carpetas, node_modules y package.json, pero no genera ninguna. Qué me recomiendan hacer?

[image: Consola cmd cuando intento instalar. No genera ninguna carpeta de node_modules ni package.json]

Comment: `npm install` es para añadir dependencias a un proyecto existente. Usa npm init para crear un proyecto (lo que generará un package.json)

Comment: Era esto nomás! muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Por lo general npm tiene problemas con algunas dependencias yo uso yarn https://yarnpkg.com/ puedes probar desinstalando node y usa la lts que es más estable.

Comment: Nunca tuve problemas complicados con `npm`, es cierto que `yarn` es más eficiente en manejo de recursos pero aún no es un reemplazo definitivo de `npm`